# Removing hyperlinks from a string without removing delimeters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of strings which have hyperlinks that need to be removed. This strings are delineated by a ,' at the end.

"This is a string with a link in it that needs to go. http://www.theonion.com,"

I tried using re.sub to do this:

```
CleanedData = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", str(datachunk))
```

But when the string ended with a hyperlink, the function removed the ," which messes things up.

```
"This is a string with a link in it that needs to go.
```

Is there some way to tell the interpreter to leave the delineators alone?

Comment: I think i did not get your question completely , but if you want to remove the last comma from a string . use rstrip function .  CleanedData = re.rstrip(",") .

Comment: @milankumar I think they want to leave the comma and only remove the URL

Comment: Use `r'http[^"\s]+'` or even `r'http[^",\s]+'`

Comment: Can you share an example of your dataframe with desired output? Asked in this form, this doesn't seem to be `pandas` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Use `\b` to match only the link.

```
import re
s = "This is a string with a link in it that needs to go. http://www.theonion.com,"
print(re.sub(r"\bhttp\S+\b", "", s))
```

**Output:**

```
This is a string with a link in it that needs to go. ,
```